# Importing and plotting social media data

Tags: r, igraph

I am currently trying to import a file such as

```
email-Eu-core-temporal.txt.gz
```

and every option that i have found does not allow me to compute the graph. The

file has V1, V2 and V3 columns, but I get the error:

> Error in graph.data.frame(dd, directed = FALSE) : 
>     the data frame should contain at least two columns

```
library(igraph)
dd<-read.csv(file.choose(), header=FALSE)
gg<-graph.data.frame(dd, directed=FALSE)
plot(gg)
```

Comment: It looks like the file is zipped. Have you tried the unzipped version as well?

Comment: Based on the [data format description here](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/email-Eu-core-temporal.html) the fields are space-delimited, not comma, so `read.csv` won't work. Try `read.table` ?

Comment: I guess read.table was the issue. Thanks! For future reference how do I know what read command to use?